# Parallel tests with Junit 4 and Maven are not working

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run the selenium UI tests in parallel with maven and Junit 4 but it's not working, only see one browser running the test.

My test suite class to run 2 test classes

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@SuiteClasses({testClass1.class, testClass2.class})
public class MySmokeTestSuite {
}
```

Maven settings

```
 <profile>
            <id>MyUISmoke</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/runner/maven/MySmokeTestSuite.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

When I run `mvn clean test -PMyUISmoke -Dtarget.env=qa_int -Ddriver-type=chrome` locally
I was expecting there are multiple browser opening and running tests in parallel but it didn't.
Did I miss something in the config?

Comment: How do you start the browser? How does your test code looks like ? I recommend to upgrade to most recent version of the plugin ans also follow naming conventions because ui tests are typcially integration tests (maven-failsafe-plugin)...